# Does Airflow clear Tasks remove data from the database also?

Tags: postgresql, airflow

We have a use case where we have to populate fresh data in our DB. There is already old data present from the successful DAG  run in our DB . Now we need to delete the old data and re run the task.
Airflow already provides a command to clear selection.

```
airflow clear -dx occupancy_reports.* -t building -s 2022-04-01 -e 2022-04-30
```

Will running this also delete the data from the Database and then populate fresh data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you meant : `airflow **tasks** clear ...`

It is only clear the set of task instance, as if they never ran (it is not rollback)

Comment: So the data would remain in the DB. And to remove the old data from DB , i will have to explicitly delete it from the DB

Comment: @rohitwtbs, yes